# How to combine 5 PDFs in one in the same page

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, generate

I'm generating a lot of PDFs and for each 5 PDFs, I want to combine then on one page.

```py
from pypdf import PdfMerger

merger = PdfMerger()

for pdf in ["out_mitry.pdf", "out_cdg.pdf"]:
    merger.append(pdf)

merger.write("result.pdf")
merger.close()
```

My actual result is getting the merge but every pdf is on one page.
I want to merge 5 pdf in one page

Comment: No, i don't think that this is possible with the `PdfFileMerger` class of `PyPDF2`. The only thing you can do is setting the page layout, which is not what you want to have. 

To get several pages of you pdf documents onto one page, i think of tools like Latex.

Comment: Is there any library in python that can do that?
I need to make a script

Comment: I don't know any, but there might be one. I don't know. But why you stick to Python? Other tools can do it easily.

Comment: Maybe this is what you looking for: https://pypi.org/project/pdfnup/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into a problem like this and found a solution.
I demonstrate solution for two one page files and you can easily extend it to any number of pdfs.

Let's combine pages this way:

```
---------
|   |   |
| 1 | 2 |
|   |   |
---------
```

```py
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader, PageObject, Transformation

pdf_filenames = ["out_mitry.pdf", "out_cdg.pdf"]

reader1 = PdfReader(pdf_filenames[0])
reader2 = PdfReader(pdf_filenames[1])

page1 = reader1.pages[0]
page2 = reader2.pages[0]

total_width = page1.mediabox.right + page2.mediabox.right
total_height = max([page1.mediabox.top, page2.mediabox.top])

new_page = PageObject.create_blank_page(width=total_width, height=total_height)

# Add first page at the 0,0 position
new_page.merge_page(page1)

# Add second page with moving along the axis x
page2.add_transformation(Transformation().translate(page1.mediabox.right, 0))
page2.mediabox = new_page.mediabox  # ensure it is visible
new_page.merge_page(page2)

writer = PdfWriter()
writer.add_page(new_page)
writer.write(open("result.pdf", "wb"))
```